# How can i have the domain pointed to a droplet and all it's subdomains pointed to another droplet on digital ocean?

Tags: dns, digital-ocean, wildcard-subdomain

I have two droplets on DigitalOcean. I want example.com to point to droplet1 and *.example.com to point to droplet2. 
Is this possible?

Comment: Yea, just add a new DNS entry that has the subdomain sub.example.com pointing to the IP of the second droplet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd edit the zone file. Let's say Droplet1's IP address is 192.168.0.1 and Droplet2's IP address is 192.168.0.2

```
*            IN A    192.168.0.2
example.com. IN A    192.168.0.1
```

So the wildcard points at Droplet2's IP address as a wildcard and example.com points as Droplet1's IP address. Does this help?

I'm using DigitalOcean but I'm running my own DNS servers but I think the syntax would be the same using Digital Ocean's name servers.